# Actual physical storage size used by snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to know the actual physical storage size used in the snowflake table.
Is the size of "ActiveBytes" in table_storage_metrics that can be obtained by the following method the actual physical storage size used by snowflake?

1.use schema my_database.information_schema;
2.select * from table_storage_metrics where table_catalog like 'my_database';
3.The "ActiveBytes" in table_storage_metrics is confirThe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a clone table, it's a little complicated because the initial data will be stored in the cloned (source) table.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Difference-between-BYTES-column-and-ACTIVE-BYTES

For regular tables, you should sum all for columns to get the actual storage used for the table: ACTIVE_BYTES, TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES, FAILSAFE_BYTES, RETAINED_FOR_CLONE_BYTES.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/table_storage_metrics.html